# Pandas to_sql using sqlalchemy with large array generates errors

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am working with a large array (~55k x 11k); too large to be stored in a numpy array (it generated a memory error when I tried to import it), so I am trying to use a database instead. For some reason I am getting errors when I use SQLAlchemy from a pandas data frame. My code is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

data1 = os.path.normpath("/home/Documents/data1.mat")
engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)

#try just the first 5 rows
tmp = pd.read_csv(data1, nrows=5, header=None, delimiter='\t')

#column names are changed to "Col0", "Col1", ..., "ColN"
tmp = tmp.rename(columns={c: "Col" + str(c) for c in tmp.columns})

tmp.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists='append')
```

This generates an error, for which I can only see the last few hundred lines. The last few lines read like this:

```
"Col10915" FLOAT,
"Col10916" FLOAT,
"Col10917" FLOAT,
"Col10918" FLOAT,
"Col10919" FLOAT,
"Col10920" FLOAT
)

]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

This address resolves to the SQLAlchemy page for OperationalError. What is the deal with this? I'm not sure where to start with this error.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are trying to create a SQLite table with ~11_000 columns?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the array is approximately 55k rows and 11k columns. To be honest, I'd prefer working with a numpy or pandas array, but I get memory failures with each of those.

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/221508) addresses the MAX_COLUMN issue, but perhaps you should look at other ways of handling this task. For example, do you really need to deal with all 11_000 columns at once? Are some of the columns repeating the same basic data element, e.g. value0001,  value0002, value0003, ... and hence could be normalized?

Comment: 55k * 11k * 8 bytes per float values would take ~5GB of RAM, this should fit on most machines (or you could use 4 byte single precision floats to take 2.4GB).  Pandas would need a lot more RAM than that to load it though (maybe 10x) so you'd need to be somewhat careful.

Comment: @GordThompson, I honestly don't know if I need to deal with 11k columns at one time. Certainly we are interested in data reduction methods, but even then we need to be able to access the array in order to, say, perform PCA. It looks like the MAX_COLUMN issue could help resolve my immediate problem, but I'm certainly open to better options for linear algebra operations...

Comment: If you could share more information on those ~11k dimensions, it would be easier to comment on normalising your dataset. Maybe you would not need to generate ~11k in the first place. It might worth to look at processes that leads to this much dimensions before talking about dimensionality reduction as an option.

Comment: Just off the top of my head: If you *really do* need to keep all 11_000 columns together and 55_000 rows is just too much to handle you might consider running your analysis on a random subset of the rows (perhaps 5_000), then repeat the process a few times with a different random sample of rows and see if the results you get are more or less the same.